# Rust musl Docker image cannot find Cargo

Tags: docker, rust, 32-bit, musl

I'm trying to get Rust running in Docker to use it for 32-bit musl builds. Ever since I updated it to use the new URL to pull rustup, I'm hitting this issue when running the container interactively using bash:

```
root@2c3549fe3169:/sample# cargo
error: command failed: 'cargo'
info: caused by: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

The weird thing is, I can see the executables

```
root@2c3549fe3169:/sample# ls -l /root/.cargo/bin/
total 101440
-rwxr-xr-x 10 root root 10383380 Feb 17 21:34 cargo
-rwxr-xr-x 10 root root 10383380 Feb 17 21:34 cargo-clippy
-rwxr-xr-x 10 root root 10383380 Feb 17 21:34 cargo-fmt
-rwxr-xr-x 10 root root 10383380 Feb 17 21:34 rls
-rwxr-xr-x 10 root root 10383380 Feb 17 21:34 rust-gdb
-rwxr-xr-x 10 root root 10383380 Feb 17 21:34 rust-lldb
-rwxr-xr-x 10 root root 10383380 Feb 17 21:34 rustc
-rwxr-xr-x 10 root root 10383380 Feb 17 21:34 rustdoc
-rwxr-xr-x 10 root root 10383380 Feb 17 21:34 rustfmt
-rwxr-xr-x 10 root root 10383380 Feb 17 21:34 rustup
root@2c3549fe3169:/sample# date
Sun Feb 17 21:34:21 UTC 2019
root@2c3549fe3169:/sample# file /root/.cargo/bin/cargo
/root/.cargo/bin/cargo: ELF 32-bit LSB shared object, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.9, with debug_info, not stripped
root@2c3549fe3169:/sample# cargo
error: command failed: 'cargo'
info: caused by: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

It is installed via:

```
RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- \
--default-toolchain 1.32.0 \
-y && \
~/.cargo/bin/rustup target add i686-unknown-linux-musl && \
echo "[build]\ntarget = \"i686-unknown-linux-musl\"" > ~/.cargo/config
```

I can see the file but I cannot seem to run it, even when I switch into that directory:

```
root@2c3549fe3169:~/.cargo/bin# ./cargo
error: command failed: 'cargo'
info: caused by: No such file or directory (os error 2)
```

This is what I see when running `ldd`:

```
root@4e21c8d37266:/volume# ldd /root/.cargo/bin/cargo
linux-gate.so.1 (0xf7f41000)
libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xf774c000)
librt.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt.so.1 (0xf7742000)
libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7723000)
libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf7705000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xf7529000)
libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xf7427000)
/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xf7f43000)
```

This is my complete Dockerfile

```
FROM i386/ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
  cmake \
  curl \
  file \
  git \
  g++ \
  python \
  make \
  nano \
  ca-certificates \
  xz-utils \
  musl-tools \
  pkg-config \
  apt-file \
  xutils-dev \
  --no-install-recommends && \
  rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*


RUN curl https://sh.rustup.rs -sSf | sh -s -- \
  --default-toolchain 1.32.0 \
  -y && \
  ~/.cargo/bin/rustup target add i686-unknown-linux-musl && \
  echo "[build]\ntarget = \"i686-unknown-linux-musl\"" > ~/.cargo/config


# Compile C libraries with musl-gcc
ENV SSL_VER=1.0.2j \
    CURL_VER=7.52.1 \
    CC=musl-gcc \
    PREFIX=/usr/local \
    PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH \
    PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig

RUN curl -sL http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-$SSL_VER.tar.gz | tar xz && \
    cd openssl-$SSL_VER && \
    ./Configure no-shared --prefix=$PREFIX --openssldir=$PREFIX/ssl no-zlib -m32 linux-elf -fPIC -fno-stack-protector && \
    make depend 2> /dev/null && make -j$(nproc) && make install && \
    cd .. && rm -rf openssl-$SSL_VER

RUN curl https://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-$CURL_VER.tar.gz | tar xz && \
    cd curl-$CURL_VER && \
    ./configure --enable-shared=no --enable-static=ssl --enable-optimize --prefix=$PREFIX --host=i686-pc-linux-gnu CFLAGS=-m32 \
      --with-ca-path=/etc/ssl/certs/ --with-ca-bundle=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt --without-ca-fallback && \
    make -j$(nproc) && make install && \
    cd .. && rm -rf curl-$CURL_VER

ENV SSL_CERT_FILE=/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt \
    SSL_CERT_DIR=/etc/ssl/certs \
    OPENSSL_LIB_DIR=$PREFIX/lib \
    OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR=$PREFIX/include \
    OPENSSL_DIR=$PREFIX \
    OPENSSL_STATIC=1 \
    PATH=/usr/local/bin:/root/.cargo/bin:$PATH

RUN echo $PATH
```

And strace'ing the `cargo` binary as per comments:

```
root@156da6108ff8:~/.cargo/bin# strace -f -e trace=execve cargo               
execve("/root/.cargo/bin/cargo", ["cargo"], 0xfffdd8fc /* 20 vars */) = 0
execve("/root/.rustup/toolchains/1.32.0-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/cargo", ["/root/.rustup/toolchains/1.32.0-"...], 0x57d95620 /* 25 vars */) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
error: command failed: 'cargo'
info: caused by: No such file or directory (os error 2)
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: `(os error 2)` is `ENOENT`, which, per `man 2 execve`, may be returned not only when file is actually not found, but also when it **can not be executed for some reason** (binary format is not supported by the kernel, etc.). That is 99% your case, but I can't spot the exact reason from first glance. Can you share full `Dockerfile` (or at least the base image you use) and the output of `uname -a` at your host?

Comment: Also, it looks like the problem is not in the `cargo` binary itself, because `os error 2` seems to be a Rust standard library output, and this means that `cargo` itself _gets successfully started_, but some _subsequent_ `execve()` fails. Try to install `strace` and run: `strace -f -e trace=execve cargo`, then look for the call which returns `-ENOENT`. This will show which binary causes the failure.

Comment: Let's pretend that not everyone has memorized what the "old" and "new" URLs are for rustup — can you share **what you actually changed**?

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks/sorry - I'm at day job currently, I'll get to replying these messages tonight. Not sure about down votes but fair enough

Comment: Sorry @DanilaKiver I'll get to it tonight

Comment: Remember that downvotes are directed at the *question*, not the person behind the question. A downvoted question is an indicator to people that it isn't currently in a good state to be answered (among other possibilities). When the question is editied, votes can be revisited and changed.

Comment: One thing that strikes me is `ELF 32-bit LSB shared object` — does your Docker container have the ability to run 32-bit applications? How and why did you choose to install a 32-bit binary?

Comment: @Shepmaster docker container doesn't looks like it does at the moment, I need to check where it's gone wrong - I've used it in the past to build 32-bit stand alone binaries by using this container. Main purpose is, my target machine is 32-bit. thanks

Comment: @DanilaKiver I've updated the question with Dockerfile and strace as well - running `uname -a` shows it's 64-bit kernel (host?). Running `file /bin/bash` shows 
`/bin/bash: ELF 32-bit LSB  executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID[sha1]=dc05f677715b7c5526272815f4f663d15924f737, stripped
`. Thanks

Comment: @Shepmaster sorry, but the problem is a bit of different plane. Running containers with i386 environment and binaries on x86_64 kernels is perfectly OK (you can easily check it by playing with `docker run -it i386/ubuntu` on x86_64 box). However, what I see from the updated question and from local tests on my 64-bit machine is that _in 32-bit container with 32-bit linker and libraries 32-bit rustup tries to run 64-bit (!) cargo_, thus it fails.

Comment: @DanilaKiver Running x86 on x86_64 depends on the correct kernel options and having the correct libraries installed; it may be true that the original image has this support (the fact that bash is 32-bit seems to be a dead giveaway...). I will rewrite my comment to be more accurate.

Comment: *Ever since I updated it* — you still haven't told us what you **changed**.  What was it **before**, and what was it **after**?

Comment: @DanilaKiver your findings seem like enough of an answer to me though.

Comment: @Shepmaster The question is how 64-bit `cargo` got into this 32-bit env. What I see is that the installer script sees `x86_64` from `uname -m` but then recognizes that it is "i686 env on 64-bit Linux" (see `get_bitness()` function in the script). It downloads 32-bit `rustup-init`, which then suddenly decides that it runs on x86_64 (probably because of `uname` again - looks like it gets called before the `execve`), hence the 64-bit `cargo`. It seems to be a bit inconsistent behavior of `rustup` installer. The workaround is to use `setarch linux32` before the installation.

Comment: @DanilaKiver see [my (now deleted) answer](https://gist.github.com/shepmaster/688160ccecc7ac6bd28bb7761326df9c) with another workaround. Either way, you should answer.

Comment: @Shepmaster I will write the detailed answer with explanations a bit later, thanks.

Comment: @DanilaKiver The shell script just downloads a Rust binary that does the real work of installing things. I'd bet that the Rust code doesn't account for a 32-on-64 situation.

Comment: @Shepmaster The change was update to the rustup URL and I used to be able to do `--with-target=i686-unknown-linux-musl` which didn't work for some reason and I presumed that option is gone in new installer so I started doing this as a separate step now `rustup target add`. Could this have caused the rustup installer to behave differently?

Comment: @DanilaKiver Thanks - that explains the odd behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, here is the summary of our investigations.

The base image used for build is `i386/ubuntu` with 32-bit environment inside, however, this image does nothing to appropriately mask the results of `uname(2)` calls (by having something like `setarch linux32` as entrypoint), so, when running on 64-bit system (your case), any process inside the build container calling `uname(2)` or `uname(1)` sees `x86_64` instead of `i686`. This is the root of the problem.

When you install `cargo`, you download and run the installation script, which detects the platform it runs on and downloads the appropriate version of `rustup-init`. The platform detection in this script recognizes correctly that it runs in 32-bit environment but on 64-bit kernel, so the script downloads 32-bit version of `rustup-init`. However, `rustup-init` decides that it runs on `x86_64` (probably it sees `x86_64` returned by `uname(2)`, but does not perform the check for "32-bit environment on 64-bit kernel" case, like the installer script does). You can see it during the installation without `-y`:

```
Current installation options:

    default host triple: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
    default toolchain: stable
    modify PATH variable: yes
```

So, `rustup` installs 64-bit toolchain, and you end up with situation when calling `cargo` results in running *64-bit binary in 32-bit environment*, so you see the error.

I still feel some sort of inconsistent behavior here, because both the installation script and `rustup-init` are [parts of the same project](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup.rs) and I don't really see the reason why should they detect the platform *differently* in the same environment (why can't `rustup-init` just be as smart as the installation script is?).

As @Shepmaster noticed, this is a known issue ([Rustup installs 64bit compiler on a 32bit Docker instance](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup.rs/issues/1282)). There are two workarounds possible:

- force the platform for the default toolchain by passing `--default-host i686-unknown-linux-gnu` to the installer;
- fool the installer by running it under `setarch linux32` so that its call to `uname(2)` will see `i686` instead of `x86_64`.

Personally, I would choose the first option, as it seems to be less hacky.